How to build AWS SAM Lambda with Image deployment on Apple Silicon
(I just filed this bug report but perhaps someone here can answer.)
sam build fails with the sam  Hello World Example when building for Image (Docker) deployment for x86_64 architecture on Apple M1 Silicon.
Under the hood, SAM will use docker to build a docker image. For some reason it's not working on my Mac. It works just fine from an AWS x86 Linux system running . So now I'm trying to run x86 AWS Linux in docker on my mac for that docker in docker experience. I haven't gotten that working yet.
Here I create a simple SAM deployment with their Hello World example and Image deployment:
simsong@Simsons-MacBook-Pro ~ % sam init

You can preselect a particular runtime or package type when using the `sam init` experience.
Call `sam init --help` to learn more.

Which template source would you like to use?
    1 - AWS Quick Start Templates
    2 - Custom Template Location
Choice: 1

Choose an AWS Quick Start application template
    1 - Hello World Example
    2 - Data processing
    3 - Hello World Example with Powertools for AWS Lambda
    4 - Multi-step workflow
    5 - Scheduled task
    6 - Standalone function
    7 - Serverless API
    8 - Infrastructure event management
    9 - Lambda Response Streaming
    10 - Serverless Connector Hello World Example
    11 - Multi-step workflow with Connectors
    12 - GraphQLApi Hello World Example
    13 - Full Stack
    14 - Lambda EFS example
    15 - DynamoDB Example
    16 - Machine Learning
Template: 1

Use the most popular runtime and package type? (python3.13 and zip) [y/N]: N

Which runtime would you like to use?
    1 - dotnet8
    2 - dotnet6
    3 - go (provided.al2)
    4 - go (provided.al2023)
    5 - graalvm.java11 (provided.al2)
    6 - graalvm.java17 (provided.al2)
    7 - java21
    8 - java17
    9 - java11
    10 - java8.al2
    11 - nodejs22.x
    12 - nodejs20.x
    13 - nodejs18.x
    14 - nodejs16.x
    15 - python3.9
    16 - python3.8
    17 - python3.13
    18 - python3.12
    19 - python3.11
    20 - python3.10
    21 - ruby3.3
    22 - ruby3.2
    23 - rust (provided.al2)
    24 - rust (provided.al2023)
Runtime: 19

What package type would you like to use?
    1 - Zip
    2 - Image
Package type: 2

Based on your selections, the only dependency manager available is pip.
We will proceed copying the template using pip.

Would you like to enable X-Ray tracing on the function(s) in your application?  [y/N]: N

Would you like to enable monitoring using CloudWatch Application Insights?
For more info, please view https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/monitoring/cloudwatch-application-insights.html [y/N]: N

Would you like to set Structured Logging in JSON format on your Lambda functions?  [y/N]: N

Project name [sam-app]: s3watch-image

    -----------------------
    Generating application:
    -----------------------
    Name: s3watch-image
    Base Image: amazon/python3.11-base
    Architectures: x86_64
    Dependency Manager: pip
    Output Directory: .
    Configuration file: s3watch-image/samconfig.toml

    Next steps can be found in the README file at s3watch-image/README.md


Commands you can use next
=========================
[*] Create pipeline: cd s3watch-image && sam pipeline init --bootstrap
[*] Validate SAM template: cd s3watch-image && sam validate
[*] Test Function in the Cloud: cd s3watch-image && sam sync --stack-name {stack-name} --watch

simsong@Simsons-MacBook-Pro ~ % sam init
simsong@Simsons-MacBook-Pro ~ % ls s3watch
drwxr-xr-x@  11 simsong  staff        352 Dec  3 06:29 s3watch
simsong@Simsons-MacBook-Pro ~ % cd s3watch-image

Observed result:
simsong@Simsons-MacBook-Pro s3watch-image % sam build
Building codeuri: /Users/simsong/s3watch-image runtime: None architecture: x86_64 functions: HelloWorldFunction
Building image for HelloWorldFunction function
Setting DockerBuildArgs for HelloWorldFunction function
Failed building function HelloWorldFunction

Build Failed
Error: failed to export image: NotFound: content digest sha256:d40a1d2caa9d01b32d5f0ce81782af06f49786c01729d03c6450ad78b06654c7: not found
simsong@Simsons-MacBook-Pro s3watch-image % sam build --debug
2024-12-03 06:32:31,563 | Config file location: /Users/simsong/s3watch-image/samconfig.toml
2024-12-03 06:32:31,565 | Loading configuration values from [default.['build'].parameters] (env.command_name.section) in config file at
'/Users/simsong/s3watch-image/samconfig.toml'...
2024-12-03 06:32:31,565 | Configuration values successfully loaded.
2024-12-03 06:32:31,566 | Configuration values are: {'stack_name': 's3watch-image', 'parallel': True}
2024-12-03 06:32:31,568 | Using SAM Template at /Users/simsong/s3watch-image/template.yaml
2024-12-03 06:32:31,586 | Using config file: samconfig.toml, config environment: default
2024-12-03 06:32:31,586 | Expand command line arguments to:
2024-12-03 06:32:31,586 | --template_file=/Users/simsong/s3watch-image/template.yaml --parallel --mount_with=READ --build_dir=.aws-sam/build
--cache_dir=.aws-sam/cache
2024-12-03 06:32:31,619 | 'build' command is called
2024-12-03 06:32:31,621 | No Parameters detected in the template
2024-12-03 06:32:31,633 | There is no customer defined id or cdk path defined for resource HelloWorldFunction, so we will use the resource logical id as the
resource id
2024-12-03 06:32:31,633 | There is no customer defined id or cdk path defined for resource ServerlessRestApi, so we will use the resource logical id as the
resource id
2024-12-03 06:32:31,634 | 0 stacks found in the template
2024-12-03 06:32:31,634 | No Parameters detected in the template
2024-12-03 06:32:31,642 | There is no customer defined id or cdk path defined for resource HelloWorldFunction, so we will use the resource logical id as the
resource id
2024-12-03 06:32:31,642 | There is no customer defined id or cdk path defined for resource ServerlessRestApi, so we will use the resource logical id as the
resource id
2024-12-03 06:32:31,643 | 2 resources found in the stack
2024-12-03 06:32:31,643 | Found Serverless function with name='HelloWorldFunction' and ImageUri='None'
2024-12-03 06:32:31,643 | --base-dir is not presented, adjusting uri ./hello_world relative to /Users/simsong/s3watch-image/template.yaml
2024-12-03 06:32:31,644 | --base-dir is not presented, adjusting uri . relative to /Users/simsong/s3watch-image/template.yaml
2024-12-03 06:32:31,645 | 2 resources found in the stack
2024-12-03 06:32:31,646 | Found Serverless function with name='HelloWorldFunction' and ImageUri='None'
2024-12-03 06:32:31,646 | Error occurred while trying to track an event: Event 'BuildFunctionRuntime' does not accept value 'None'.
2024-12-03 06:32:31,647 | Instantiating build definitions
2024-12-03 06:32:31,648 | Unique function build definition found, adding as new (Function Build Definition: BuildDefinition(None, /Users/simsong/s3watch-image,
Image, , 048ddf94-9def-4802-9031-236c4ab70d34, {'Dockerfile': 'Dockerfile', 'DockerContext': '/Users/simsong/s3watch-image/hello_world', 'DockerTag':
'python3.11-v1'}, {}, x86_64, []), Function: Function({'function_id': 'HelloWorldFunction', 'name': 'HelloWorldFunction', 'functionname': 'HelloWorldFunction',
'runtime': None, 'memory': None, 'timeout': 3, 'handler': None, 'imageuri': None, 'packagetype': 'Image', 'imageconfig': None, 'codeuri':
'/Users/simsong/s3watch-image', 'environment': None, 'rolearn': None, 'layers': [], 'events': {'HelloWorld': {'Type': 'Api', 'Properties': {'Path': '/hello',
'Method': 'get', 'RestApiId': 'ServerlessRestApi'}}}, 'metadata': {'Dockerfile': 'Dockerfile', 'DockerContext': '/Users/simsong/s3watch-image/hello_world',
'DockerTag': 'python3.11-v1', 'SamResourceId': 'HelloWorldFunction'}, 'inlinecode': None, 'codesign_config_arn': None, 'architectures': ['x86_64'],
'function_url_config': None, 'function_build_info': <FunctionBuildInfo.BuildableImage: ('BuildableImage', 'Regular IMAGE function which can be build with SAM
CLI')>, 'stack_path': '', 'runtime_management_config': None, 'logging_config': None}))
2024-12-03 06:32:31,651 | Async execution started
2024-12-03 06:32:31,651 | Invoking function functools.partial(<bound method ParallelBuildStrategy.build_single_function_definition of
<samcli.lib.build.build_strategy.ParallelBuildStrategy object at 0x1046c5d30>>, <samcli.lib.build.build_graph.FunctionBuildDefinition object at 0x10469ead0>)
2024-12-03 06:32:31,652 | Building codeuri: /Users/simsong/s3watch-image runtime: None architecture: x86_64 functions: HelloWorldFunction
2024-12-03 06:32:31,652 | Waiting for async results
2024-12-03 06:32:31,652 | Building to following folder /Users/simsong/s3watch-image/.aws-sam/build/HelloWorldFunction
2024-12-03 06:32:31,653 | Building image for HelloWorldFunction function
2024-12-03 06:32:31,660 | Setting DockerBuildArgs for HelloWorldFunction function
2024-12-03 06:32:33,053 | Failed building function HelloWorldFunction
2024-12-03 06:32:33,054 | Exception raised during the execution

Build Failed
2024-12-03 06:32:33,054 | Telemetry endpoint configured to be https://aws-serverless-tools-telemetry.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/metrics
2024-12-03 06:32:33,123 | Telemetry endpoint configured to be https://aws-serverless-tools-telemetry.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/metrics
2024-12-03 06:32:33,124 | Unable to find Click Context for getting session_id.
2024-12-03 06:32:33,124 | Sending Telemetry: {'metrics': [{'commandRun': {'requestId': '91b69b44-e223-413b-8197-a491fb57a6aa', 'installationId':
'98c02822-e59c-4cca-b055-9f3a4ae5aeb9', 'sessionId': 'ee4b716e-27ca-4da6-b7b5-af3022a8fe53', 'executionEnvironment': 'CLI', 'ci': False, 'pyversion': '3.13.0',
'samcliVersion': '1.131.0', 'awsProfileProvided': False, 'debugFlagProvided': True, 'region': '', 'commandName': 'sam build', 'metricSpecificAttributes':
{'projectType': 'CFN', 'gitOrigin': None, 'projectName': '20fe256ae70c5ee8593658e2d9ef6fac9b4264285f663c6d408486ef9e0c7bc8', 'initialCommit': None}, 'duration':
1468, 'exitReason': 'DockerBuildFailed', 'exitCode': 1}}]}
2024-12-03 06:32:33,126 | Sending Telemetry: {'metrics': [{'events': {'requestId': '6d243618-8e7f-40ce-8dff-674123e5a67f', 'installationId':
'98c02822-e59c-4cca-b055-9f3a4ae5aeb9', 'sessionId': 'ee4b716e-27ca-4da6-b7b5-af3022a8fe53', 'executionEnvironment': 'CLI', 'ci': False, 'pyversion': '3.13.0',
'samcliVersion': '1.131.0', 'commandName': 'sam build', 'metricSpecificAttributes': {'events': [{'event_name': 'SamConfigFileExtension', 'event_value': '.toml',
'thread_id': '50e0538b120f4050943efa3afbad8379', 'time_stamp': '2024-12-03 11:32:31.563', 'exception_name': None}, {'event_name': 'SamConfigFileExtension',
'event_value': '.toml', 'thread_id': '701826bd8bca45c5b77bede5b12c25e1', 'time_stamp': '2024-12-03 11:32:31.586', 'exception_name': None}]}}}]}
2024-12-03 06:32:33,389 | HTTPSConnectionPool(host='aws-serverless-tools-telemetry.us-west-2.amazonaws.com', port=443): Read timed out. (read timeout=0.1)
2024-12-03 06:32:33,390 | HTTPSConnectionPool(host='aws-serverless-tools-telemetry.us-west-2.amazonaws.com', port=443): Read timed out. (read timeout=0.1)
Error: failed to export image: NotFound: content digest sha256:d40a1d2caa9d01b32d5f0ce81782af06f49786c01729d03c6450ad78b06654c7: not found

Expected result:

It should build a SAM package that I can then deploy.
This works if I specify a Zip deployment, rather than image.

Additional environment details (Ex: Windows, Mac, Amazon Linux etc)

OS: MacOS Sequoia 15.1.1
sam --version: SAM CLI, version 1.131.0
AWS region: us-east-1

# Paste the output of `sam --info` here
{
  "version": "1.131.0",
  "system": {
    "python": "3.13.0",
    "os": "macOS-15.1.1-arm64-arm-64bit-Mach-O"
  },
  "additional_dependencies": {
    "docker_engine": "27.3.1",
    "aws_cdk": "Not available",
    "terraform": "Not available"
  },
  "available_beta_feature_env_vars": [
    "SAM_CLI_BETA_FEATURES",
    "SAM_CLI_BETA_BUILD_PERFORMANCE",
    "SAM_CLI_BETA_TERRAFORM_SUPPORT",
    "SAM_CLI_BETA_RUST_CARGO_LAMBDA"
  ]
}


This works without problem if I repeat the same steps from an EC2 instance running x86 AWS Linux.
